# Enabling http strict transport security in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, hsts

I am trying to enable hsts in my application.I have modified my web.xml like this.This is WEB-INF web.xml and not inside tomcat

web.xml

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <init-param>
    <param-name>maxAgeSeconds</param-name>
   <param-value>31536000</param-value>
   </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>includeSubDomains</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
      <param-value>DENY</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I am checking my website url with this test tool https://tools.geekflare.com but nothing is enabled.All are showing cross mark.But in the above configuration if i remove hsts thing that is if i deploy this below xml then X-XSS-Protection Header,X-Frame-Options Header Header,X-Content-Type-Options Header are enabled but not HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Header.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
      <param-value>DENY</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
  <filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone tell how to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Header? in tomcat 7?

Comment: have u resolved this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Is the application behind a proxy? Is the application server handling https or something else?